# Can Ker(T) = Im(T) of a linear transformation of R raised to a power?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So I know this can be true for when T:R -> R, but does this apply for when R is raised to any power? Would this also work if, for example, we had R^3?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How can you have a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ such that $\ker(T) = \operatorname{im}(T)$? It's literally impossible by dimension theorem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ is a linear transformation, then [Rank-Nullity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) asserts that $$\dim \ker(T)+\dim\operatorname{Im}(T)=n.$$

So, if $\dim\ker T=\dim\operatorname{Im} T=k$, then $n=2k$.

So if $n=3$ or any other odd number, this is IMPOSSIBLE.

For EVEN $n$ it is possible:
Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_k,e_{k+1},\dots,e_{2k}\}$ be a basis for $\Bbb R^{2k}$.
Define $T(e_j)=e_{k+j}$ for $1\le j\le k$ and $T(e_j)=0$ for $k+1\le j\le 2k$.

Then $\ker t=\operatorname{Im} T=span\{e_{k+1},\dots,e_{2k}\}$.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. I hadn't considered that dim(ker(T)) being equal to dim(Im(T)) would mean n=2k but it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb R$, there are no such application. In $\mathbb R^2$, there are many... for example, if $T$ is defined s.t. $$T(1,0)=(0,1)\quad \text{and}\quad T(0,1)=(0,0),$$
extend over $\mathbb R^2$ by $\mathbb R-$linearity.

Answer (score 0):

It is true if T is a projection i.e. T2=T.But in general you may take the counterexample T(ϵ1)=ϵ2 and T(ϵ2)=0,on R2 over the field R.Here RangeT=KerT.Although for any finite dimensional vector space V there is a k such that V=R(Tk)⊕N(Tk).